# Vue/laravel - passing data from blade to vue component

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am new to Vue, and just learning it, so I wonder how to modify a component that I have which works fine for the create form, I would like to modified it so that I can use it for the edit form as well. What I need to do is to set the image src to the one I get from the DB if it exists. How can I achieve that?
This is the component file:

```
<template>
<div>
  <div v-if="!image">
    <h2>Select an image</h2>
    <input type="file" @change="onFileChange">
  </div>
  <div v-else>
    <img :src="image" />
    <input type="file" name="image" style="display:none">
    <button @click="removeImage">Remove image</button>
  </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
        image: '',
        formData:new FormData(),
        file: null
        }
    },
    methods: {
        onFileChange: function onFileChange(e) {
            var files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
            if (!files.length)
                return;
            this.createImage(files[0]);
            this.formData.append('file', files[0]);
            this.file = files[0];
        },
        createImage: function createImage(file) {
            var image = new Image();
            var reader = new FileReader();
            var vm = this;
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                vm.image = e.target.result;
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        },
        removeImage: function removeImage(e) {
            this.image = '';
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

I have tried with doing this in my view:

```
<image-upload :image="/uploads/{{ $magazine->image }}"></image-upload>
```

But I get the error:

> [Vue warn]: failed to compile template ...invalide expression

**Update**:

I did as suggested in the answers and removed the `:` from the directive, and it worked but I get a warning message now in the console:

> [Vue warn]: The data property "image" is already declared as a prop.
>   Use prop default value instead. (found in component )

Comment: try removing the `:` from the image directive. since it's a string it doesn't need processing as a Javascript expression. so `<image-upload image="/uploads/{{ $magazine->image }}"></image-upload>`

Comment: Yes, that helped! It works now, but I get a warning message in the console, would you know how to get rid of this:  [Vue warn]: The data property "image" is already declared as a prop. Use prop default value instead. (found in component <image-upload>)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The prop warning is because you have image in your data property

```
data() {
    return {
    image: '',
    formData:new FormData(),
    file: null
    }
},
```

you need to remove it from there and add it to the props property

```
props: {
    image: {
        type: String,
        default: ""
    }
},
data() {
    return {
    formData: new FormData(),
    file: null
    }
},
```

Comment: Thank you! It removed the previous warning, but now I have a new one:`vue.js?0598:2574 [Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "image" (found in component <image-upload>)`

Comment: that would be because you have `this.image = ''` in remove image. it would prefer if you had a data or computed value that gets assigned the image prop on loading and then internally updated. this stops the image value being overwritten when the vue virtual dom gets redrawn.

Comment: Could you if it is not a problem give a code example of how to do that? Because, at the moment I can't upload an image on the update form. I have posted a question about it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40057627/vue-laravel-uploading-a-file-on-update-doesnt-work)